# No Encoder found for play.api.libs.json.JsValue

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, playframework, play-json

I have case classes like these

```
 case class PrimeraRemoteCopyConfig(
    links: Option[Vector[JsObject]] = None,
    status: Option[Vector[JsObject]] = None,
    targets: Option[Vector[JsObject]] = None,
    groups: Option[Vector[JsObject]] = None,
    groupTargets: Option[Vector[JsObject]] = None,
    groupVolumes: Option[Vector[JsObject]] = None)


object PrimeraRemoteCopyConfig {
    implicit val _format = Json.format[PrimeraRemoteCopyConfig]
}

case class PrimeraConfig(
   systemUid: String,
   tenantId: String,
   systemWWN: String,
    remoteCopyConfig: Option[PrimeraRemoteCopyConfig] = None)

object PrimeraConfig {

  implicit val _format = Json.format[PrimeraConfig]

}
```

And I have spark dataset that uses state management, using `flatMapGroupsWithState`.

However I am getting

```
 22/05/10 17:07:48 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 192.168.0.199, 53277, None)
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for play.api.libs.json.JsValue
- map value class: "play.api.libs.json.JsValue"

```
- field (class: "scala.collection.Map", name: "underlying")
- array element class: "play.api.libs.json.JsObject"
- option value class: "scala.collection.immutable.Vector"
- field (class: "scala.Option", name: "links")
- option value class: "model.PrimeraRemoteCopyConfig"
- field (class: "scala.Option", name: "remoteCopyConfig")
- root class: "model.PrimeraConfig"
at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.cannotFindEncoderForTypeError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:1000)
```

I tried defining encoders for JsObject using Encoders.product[JsObject] However it does not work. What am I doing wrongly here

Comment: I doubt it make much sense to encoder `JsObject` or `JsValue`, which are themselves AST for the JSON representation, rather stringify.

Comment: As a completion to @cchantep 's comment, maybe this [sparkbyexample post](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-most-used-json-functions-with-examples/) would help.

Comment: Amazing  , I am going to mark as resolved as, I had stringified it yesterday